# Typescript Generic Enum Type used to determine type of interface field

Tags: typescript

I would like to prepare an interface with generic enum argument which would determine the type of one of the properties.

After long battle I managed to obtain something like this:

```
type NeverAlternative<T, P, N> = [T] extends [never] ? P : N;

export interface ProjectKpi<T extends KpiType | never = never> {
   values: NeverAlternative<T, BaseKpiValues, KpiTypeToSpecificValuesTypeMap[T]>; 
}
```

where `KpiType` is the typescript string enum defining served KPIs and `KpiTypeToSpecificValuesTypeMap` is an util interface like

```
interface KpiTypeToSpecificValuesTypeMap
  extends Record<KpiType, BaseKpiValues> {
  [KpiType.performanceMonth]: PerformanceMonthValues;
  [KpiType.lastMonthPerformance]: LastMonthPerformanceValues;
}
```

used as type map to determine the proper type of `values` field. Both `PerformanceMonthValues` and `LastMonthPerformanceValues` define the desired structure of `values` field for give KPI type. The extension from `Record<>` works as fall back for such values of `KpiTypes` enum which are not specified and it's `values` field should have type `BaseKpiValues`

I used `never` as default type and check whether argument `T` exists (is passed) - if not it has type `never`, to be able to use `ProjectKpi` interface without type argument ( when I'm not able to know what KPI type is it ).

Till this point I didn't have any problem but I need to implement method which takes argument of `KpiTypes` type and returns the `ProjectKpi` with proper values type.
E.g: `fun(KpiType.performanceMonth)` should return `ProjectKpi<KpiType.performanceMonth>` with `PerformanceMonthValues` as type of `values` field.

I came up with (as arrow function):

```
<T extends KpiType>(type: T) =>
      this.getKpis.find<ProjectKpi<T>>((kpi: ProjectKpi) => kpi.type === type);
```

but I have following error:

```
Type 'ProjectKpi<T>' does not satisfy the constraint 'ProjectKpi<never>'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    Type 'KpiType' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Please help! I believe in strength of Stack Overflow!

Comment: What is `this.getKpis`? Is it an array?

Comment: Yes, it's an array of type ProjectKpi[].

Comment: The `kpi` argument in your arrow function is typed as `ProjectKpi`. But `ProjectKpi` is generic and expects a type argument, otherwise it defaults to `ProjectKpi<never>`. So your error is because `T` is not equal to `never` so you can't create the `ProjectKpi<T>` type which is what you've said you want from this.getKpis.find

Comment: I see. 
Do you have any suggestion how I could change `ProjectKpi` to have such behavior:
When I pass generic type argument to `ProjectKpi `like `ProjectKpi<KpiType. performanceMonth>` I get type with `values` corresponding to argument.

And when I do not pass it like `ProjectKpi` I get type with `values` of `BaseKpiValues`

Comment: Propably I'm using `never` in a wrong way.